# What is the meaning of 'Rajoyoga' and 'Tamoyoga'

Tags: yoga, gunas, rajasic, tamasic

In Ganapati stavah, I came across two words 'Rajoyoga' and 'Tamoyoga' in shloka 4 and 6 respectively:-
https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_ganesha/gaNapatistavaH.html

What is the meaning of the above two words here? I understand the three gunas But what is the contex with yoga here?

Comment: it is the sandhi of rajas and yoga similarly tamas and yoga

Comment: Yes, it is Sandhi , but what that mean is yoga of 3 types as well? Shouldn't yoga always be sattvic? And what would rajasic or tamasic yoga mean in context of Lord Ganesha ?

Comment: It also means union, done with full effort, ...